# Laravel Action Controller redefined with Ajax URL

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, routes

have a laravel routing question. I am creating an AJAX form to submit a new contact. However, my form is never submitted since it is not routing correctly...

```
$('#contact-add').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ URL::action('ContactsController@ajaxCreateContact') }}",
                data: $('#contact-add').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
```

So it should be routing to my controller...however when I check the Console Log it is trying to pass it to POST http://contact.dev/ajax-create-contact 500 (Internal Server Error). So it is adding the sites URL in front of the controller and thus never reaching it. How can I escape the local URL so that it just redirects to ContactsController@ajaxCreateContact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put blade templating in your JS just type the URI.

Comment: Open your network tab in your developer tools and click the red, read the error in the preview.